# Laravel: MySQL query getting slower after some time. What are the possible reasons?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, composer-php

I have a laravel project copied from OSX+WAMP to windows7+XAMPP with the database data dumped with a sql file. At first it runs smoothly but after using the system for an afternoon, a page with a MySQL query suddenly response very slowly. (originally 1-2 seconds to now over 15 seconds) I am just reading the code and have made absolutely no changes. I have no idea why, so I tried to delete the project and the database and dump everything once again. It solves the problem.

The same things repeated for the 3rd time again today and still no changes is made. With the project running on production server for more than a year, I am sure the code is fine even though it is not written by me. I have no problem in accessing the data using HeidiSQL, so it is not the problem of database. I guess there maybe something related to the laravel settings on windows. Anyone got any idea on what may be the reason?

I know running the project on a VM may solves the problem, but I really want to know the exact reason. Having an unknown problem doesn't feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the exact mechanism but it turns out to be related to how laravel load files differently under different environments.

The problem is that the one who passed the code to me do backups of previous versions in the same folder where the production codes are, only changing the file name but not changing the class name. (Git is still not available when the previous version is made) That previous version do query in a slow way and cause the slow query problem I mentioned. When I deleted these backup files, the correct ones are loaded and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clockwork/dmggabnehkmmfmdffgajcflpdjlnoemp for profiling it and find out where the bottleneck is, make sure is it a mysql problem or php problem.

below is peek :

[image]